# How do I pull a list from an MArgList in maya?(Python)

Tags: python, maya

Edit(solution?): I was able to achieve this by converting my arrays into a string and parsing through and recreating them on the other end.  If anyone has a better way I would appreciate it.

Original:

I created a class that extends `MPxCommand` to create a plug-in and have been trying to figure out how to parse the `MArgList` in the `doIt()` function to pull a couple of lists from from the args variable.  I am trying to pull a list of strings and a list ints that will have an inconsistent length so I won't be able to (I think) fill the flag multiple times when I call the command.

I've had success pulling individual variables with `MArgParser` but have not found a way to pull a full list.

`MArgList` appears to have what I want with the function `asStringArray(index)` and `asIntArray(index)` but when I use try using them I get the error:

```
# Error: TypeError: file Command.py line 163: in method 'MArgList_asIntArray', argument 2 of type 'unsigned int &' #
```

Edit:

```
class myCommand(omMPx.MPxCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        omMPx.MPxCommand.__init__(self)

    def newSyntax(self):
        syntax = om.MSyntax()

        syntax.addFlag("-s", "-string", om.MSyntax.kString)
        return syntax

    def doIt(self, args):

        stringFlag = "-s"
        parser = om.MArgParser(self.newSyntax(),args)

        if parser.isFlagSet(stringFlag):
            self.myStr = parser.flagArgumentString(stringFlag, 0)
            print self.myStr
```

This code will put "hello" from the `args` into `self.myStr` if I run `cmds.myCommand(s = "hello")`, but I'd like to be able to be able to run `cmds.myCommand(s = ["hello", "world"])` and be able to get the array from the `args` variable and put it into `self.myStr`.

I hope that clears up what I'm trying to do.

Comment: can you share your code? it's not easy to follow your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the declaration of that function:

```
'MArgList_asIntArray', argument 2 of type 'unsigned int &'
```

`int &` is a reference to an int, i.e. an int you give to the function, the function will change it, and your variable will reflect the changes.

So maybe you already see it: passing a constant is not possible.

I'm not into python at all, so I don't know if it would be sufficient to simply declare an int, initialize it and then pass it as argument 2 to the function.